# Error at runtime - what to do?

Tags: android, mobile, runtime-error

What does this error mean? I'm having this error at runtime. The app crashes when I try to launch. I am new at Android programming.

I have tried to look through the code and I couldn't find it. I would appreciate your help.

```
02-07 14:32:57.967: E/Trace(943): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quiz/com.example.quiz.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.quiz.Splash" on path: /data/app/com.example.quiz-2.apk
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.quiz.Splash" on path: /data/app/com.example.quiz-2.apk
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
02-07 14:32:58.386: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, check if your source is where it is mentioned in the error log.
2. If it is, check if you've made any typing mistakes
3. If it still isn't working, it would be easier (In my opinion) to create a new project and rename what is missing (I've done this several times already and it has always worked) Of course, make sure you copy all of your code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've missed out your Splash activity in your manifest.

```
    <activity android:name=".Splash"/>
```

See if that line appears in your manifest, if not you should add it.

Comment: if it were not, this would be posted in the errorlog, kinda `have you declared in your manifest.xml` was to me often ^^

Comment: The problem was the package name. I copied some of the files from another package name and forgot to change it.

Beginner mistake